# How to loop over an attribute of a subject in RSpec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

Is it possible to loop through the subject attribute like so:

```
subject { assignment }

its(:submissions).each do |submission|
  submission.grade should eq 100
end
```

The error I got was that `Undefined method each for Class ...`

I also tried

```
subject { assignment }
its(:submissions) do
  each do |submission|
    submission.grade should eq 100
  end
end
```

and get

> undefined method `each' for
>   RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_4::Nested_4::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x00000005f91ac8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the subject back in an example with the `subject` method. So you can do what you want this way:

```
subject { assignment }
it "has some number of submissions, each with a grade of 100" do
  subject.submissions.each { |submission| submission.grade.should eq 100 }
end
```

Side note: [Explicitly using `subject` makes your tests harder to read.](http://blog.davidchelimsky.net/blog/2012/05/13/spec-smell-explicit-use-of-subject/) Instead, use `let`:

```
let(:assignment) { create :assignment } # or whatever is necessary to create the assignment
it "has some number of submissions, each with a grade of 100" do
  assignment.submissions.each { |submission| submission.grade.should eq 100 }
end
```